# Avoid xlam reference on other pcs

Tags: vba, add-in, excel-addins, xlsm

I've made an xlam addin to use many common functions I have to use regularly. Thing is whenever I send a workbook that uses these functions to another pc, the cell that calls it makes a reference to my xlam's path... which makes sense.

I'd like to know if there's any way to avoid this behaviour so I can make my xlsm files portable. Maybe a way to programmatically add all the addin modules to the workbook whenever a xlam function is used.

Comment: Why not just place the add-in in a network location, and the everybody gets a fully functional XLSM with all of the add-in goodness. And you update the add-in in one location, and everybody gets the updates.

Comment: Should find out what is linking back to your PC and work around to avoid it. Sounds like UDF are at play here. The method will really depend on how your environment is setup. It will be complicated for an AddIn to update itself only using VBA.

Comment: @ThunderFrame Because many times we send these files to pcs out of the network.

Comment: I would make a `.xltm` macro enabled template and create new one from it to send to outside world (save as `.xlsm`). But need to ensure the recipients can receive and run your macro. Sign it with a self-signed digital certificate, get recipients to add it to Trusted Publishers and set macro security settings appropiately on their end.